# Game series probability

Tags: probability

I have a few exam review questions that I don't know how to solve. Maybe someone can help me out.

Two hockey teams play a best-of-seven series (play until a team wins a total of 4 games)

> Assume team A has a probability of 3/4 of beating team B.
>
> Assume the results of the games are independent
>
> What is the probability that all seven games will be played in the series

Answer (score 2):

The series lasts $7$ games precisely if the first $6$ games are evenly split between the two teams. So we want the probability that Team A wins $3$ of the first $6$ games and loses $3$. The probability of that is
$$\binom{6}{3}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3.$$